# Flatten() function of Fpdm libray gives error - FPDF-Merge Error: "Sorry but pdftk binary is not provided"

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDM library of FPDF to fill my pdf form and then trying to flatten it.

My code is :

```
$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My name',
    'address' => 'My address',
    'city'    => 'My city',
    'phone'   => 'My phone number'
);

$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$pdf->Load( $fields, false ); 
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Flatten();
$pdf->Output();
```

But it gives error saying - FPDF-Merge Error: Sorry but pdftk binary is not provided .

As I am a new developer i have very less idea of existing libraries.

So Please help me to find the cause of this error and solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

fpdm requires [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for some features, [including flatten](https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm/blob/master/src/fpdm.php#L23-L24).

```
*   V2.5 (06.12.2010) pdftk support for flatten mode and more...special        *
*   christmas release to the fpdf fanclub even if the red guy is busy          *
```

There is a related question in the [issue queue](https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm/issues/23).

Unfortunately it's hard to find a pure PHP solution for manipulating PDFs.